# Can't install pillow under virtualenv on Ubuntu 14

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv, python-imaging-library

I am using virtualenv.
When I run `pip install pillow` under it I get following:

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:
'/windows/code/linux/cups/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py'
```

When I use `sudo pip install pillow` I get it installed globally, and pip freeze under virtualenv don't display it (global does)

How can I install pillow under virtualenv?

### Solved:

Used `sudo -i` to get root, then activated virtualenv, and `pip install pillow` worked correctly.

Comment: What kind of folder is `/windows/`?

Comment: Please paste the entire traceback.

Answer (score 0):

try as su, no sudo.

```
su
```

enter to you virtualenv
and:

```
pip install pillow
```

Comment: thx for idea to get root before activating virtualenv. It worked.